# List of class methods with Napoleon Sphinx extension using NumPyDoc style

Tags: python, documentation, numpydoc, sphinx-napoleon

I am using NumPyDoc-style docstrings to document a Python package. I would like to switch from the ['numpydoc'](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpydoc?) Sphinx extension to [Napoleon](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.1/ext/napoleon.html#module-sphinx.ext.napoleon), because I find that it formats the docstring in a more compact and readable way. However, it does not list the methods of a class at the top of the documentation, which I find a very valuable feature of numpydoc. Does anyone know how to switch this on manually in Napoleon?

Answer (score 0):

`sphinx.ext.autosummary` helps to achieve a Sphinx table of contents for the lists of class methods and attributes

I went through both the numpydoc and Sphinx documentation to understand how it works. Do find the details below.

**SECTION 1** : understanding working of numpydoc

**Numpydoc [documentation](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)** provides an explanation how the table of all class methods is implemented by default. It internally uses `sphinx.ext.autosummary` and `numpydoc_class_members_toctree`

- when *numpydoc* is added to extensions option in `conf.py`,  `sphinx.ext.autosummary` will automatically be loaded as well.
- The following configurations options are True by default in numpydoc

  ```
  numpydoc_show_class_members = True #shows all members of a class in the Methods and Attributes 
  numpydoc_show_inherited_class_members = True #shows all inherited members of a class 
  numpydoc_class_members_toctree = True #creates a Sphinx table of contents for the lists of class methods and attributes.
  ```

**SECTION 2** : implementation with Sphinx extensions

**Sphinx extensions** : To implement table of all class methods, use *autosummary* along with *autodoc* extensions

[Napolean documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/sphinxcontrib-napoleon/downloads/pdf/latest/) quotes

> Napoleon interprets every docstring that Sphinx `autodoc` can find, including docstrings on: modules, classes,
> attributes, methods, functions, and variables

That is `sphinx.ext.napoleon` works along `sphinx.ext.autodoc`

1. First step is to explicitly include both `sphinx.ext.autodoc` and `sphinx.ext.autosummary` when you include `sphinx.ext.napoleon` in
   **extensions** option in your Sphinx `conf.py`

   ```
   extensions = [
     'sphinx.ext.autodoc',  # Core Sphinx library for auto html doc generation from docstrings
     'sphinx.ext.autosummary',  # Create neat summary tables for modules/classes/methods etc    
     'sphinx.ext.napoleon', # Support for NumPy and Google style docstrings  
   ]
   ```
2. Second steps is to select directive and relevant options, [autodoc documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc) provides 3 directives automodule, autoclass and autoexception to document a module, class or exception respectively

   ```
   .. autoclass:: Noodle       
      :members:    #option to generate document for the members of the target module, class or exception
      :undoc-members:      #option to generate document for the members not having docstrings
      :inherited-members:  #option to include members inherited from base classes
      :private-members:    #option to generate document for the private members
      :special-members:  #option to generate document for the special members (like __special__)
   ```

   If you want set the above options as default in autodoc, you can set them in **`autodoc_default_options`** as [mentioned in this documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_options)

   ```
      autodoc_default_options = {
          'members': True,
          'imported-members': True,
          'undoc-members': True,
      }
   ```

   > Other supported options are 'members', 'member-order', 'undoc-members', 'private-members', 'special-members', 'inherited-members', 'show-inheritance', 'ignore-module-all', 'imported-members', 'exclude-members', 'class-doc-from','imported-members', 'class-doc-from'
3. Third and final step to set relevant options, [autosummary documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html#directive-autosummary) generates autodoc summaries i.e., function/method/attribute summary lists

   ```
   .. autosummary::
      :toctree: DIRNAME              #example from documentation

      sphinx.environment.BuildEnvironment
      sphinx.util.relative_uri
   ```

   > The autosummary directive can also optionally serve as a **toctree** entry for the included items. Optionally, stub .rst files for these items can also be automatically generated when autosummary_generate is True.

   The following **configuration** options should also be set in your Sphinx `conf.py`:

   ```
   # generate autosummary even if no references
   autosummary_generate = True
   autosummary_imported_members = True
   ```

Comment: This seems very close, but when I tried this on a class, the table created by autosummary contained only a single line item for the class itself - it did not include members. Is this your experience? If not, I must be missing something.

Comment: autosummary’s options must be set to **True** namely `autosummary_generate` and `autosummary_imported_members`. Note that autosummary is also dependent on `autodoc` extension so you must include autoclass directive as mentioned in step 2. I have also included 3 complete steps to follow

Comment: Ah - I *was* missing something. It creates an rst file in the DIRNAME and *that* is where the new TOC is found.

Comment: In step 2, I have also included a way to set the default behaviour of autodoc `autodoc_default_options`, depending on your requirements you can add the required supported options like `inherited-members` mentioned below. Do follow the 3 important steps

Answer (score -1):

I am new to Napoleon/Sphinx, but I think the answer might be in Sphinx, rather than Napoleon.

If you have autodoc enabled in conf.py, eg.

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.coverage']
```

then add to your index.rst (say):

```
.. autoclass:: module_name.class_name
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
```

where `module_name` contains the class in question, then `class_name` will be in the documentation along with all of its methods, even if they do not currently have a docstring.

Comment: The issue is not that methods are not showing at all, but rather there is no hyperlinked list of methods at the top (like a table of contents).

Comment: @SethMMorton might I just clarify your question, so you are looking to switch from numpydoc to sphinx ext napoleon. And Your question is more related to table of contents

Comment: The official documentation for sphinx(napoleon) in the question latest software update was in 2016 apart from this, are you open to any new solutions as well?

Comment: @ArchanaDavid The question is this: with the numpydoc extension a table of all class methods created in class documentation which greatly aids discoverability. Napoleon does not do this, at least by default, but it is the assumption of the OP and myself that there must be a way to enable it and we would like to know how.

Comment: @ArchanaDavid And yes, any viable solution is fine.